# Check if current user belongs to a sharepoint security group using REST/Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint site on which "Everyone except external users" have view access.
Now , there is a set of users(say approx 120 users) for whom I want to restrict site access.
So , I have created a security group and added them on it. Now I want to check ,if user belongs to security group , he must get access denied while accessing site.

I know how to check user for an SP group, but for security group, will REST/Javascript will work?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please refer this answer - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212653/javascript-rest-check-if-current-user-belongs-to-security-group

Comment: With reference to above link, I cannot differentiate the granted actions for everyone and these set of users, as they also belong to "Everyone except external users" group.